# Logic App IP Address when we call API Management

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

Below is my scenario:

I am calling API Management from Logic APP.

I want to restrict IP Address so that only Logic App can call the API  Management.

I am using the IP Filter as shown below for the IP Address mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config)

```
<ip-filter action="allow | forbid">  
<address>40.112.243.160</address>  
<address>address</address>  
</ip-filter>
```

But I am not able to figure out the IP Address that's coming in to API Management. Its different than the list of IP Address provided in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config). It starts with 10.*.*.*.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: You could check `X-Forwarded-For` attribute in your logic app output to get the IP address. I have update my reply, you could refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is a list of outbound IP addresses for Azure Logic App per region. For more details, you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#configuration). If you want to avoid other users with the Logic App in the same region to have access to your resource or get a static single IP address, you can further use Azure API Management to act as a reverse proxy for the Logic App. And then use the policy in the APIM as below:

```
<ip-filter action="allow | forbid">  
<address>address</address>  
<address-range from="address" to="address" />  
</ip-filter>
```

Comment: This is what I had done. But the IP Address I am seeing from Logic APP to APIM is different. It starts with 10... which I don't see any where in the documentation. That's where I am confused if the IP Address I am depending from Logic App is right?

Answer (score 0):

All logic apps in a region use the same ranges of IP addresses. To support the calls that logic apps directly make with HTTP, HTTP + Swagger, and other HTTP requests, set up your firewall configurations in your APIM so they include these outbound addresses, based on where your logic apps exist:

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#configuration-ip-addresses) is the list of IP address of Logic App based on the region.

Comment: Please add the list of IP Addresses to your post in case the link goes dead

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ip-filter` [policy filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs) (**allows/denies**) calls from specific IP addresses and/or address ranges in your APIM.

**Policy statement**

```
<ip-filter action="allow | forbid">  
    <address>address</address>  
    <address-range from="address" to="address" />  
</ip-filter>
```

You could get your logic app ip address from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#configuration-ip-addresses). Then you could set APIM like:

```
<ip-filter action="allow">  
    <address>address1</address>  
    <address>address2</address> 
    <address>address3</address> 
</ip-filter>
```

**Update**:

> But I am not able to figure out the IP Address that's coming in to API Management. Its different than the list of IP Address provided in this link.

When you use logic app to call APIM, you could see the [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) attribute in output which is a common method for **identifying the originating IP address of a client** connecting to a web server through an HTTP proxy or load balancer.

Here is my test snapshot. My logic app location is `eastasia` and my IP address is `13.75.94.173` which is inside the [East Asia Outbound IP of Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config#configuration-ip-addresses).

[image]